# Why would my zipped file be the same size as the uncompressed files?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip

I am trying to zip 13 `mp4s`. The uncompressed versions of those files are 2.69GB.

But when I zip them with 7zip, using `Ultra` compression level and any of the compression methods - including `LZMA`, the resulting file is still 2.69GB.

Why is that?

**Edit 1**

I am even trying it in the 7z format, and as you can see from the image below the Compression Ratio is 99%! That doesn't provide me much compression at all.

The settings I used for `.7z` are `LZMA2`

[image: 7z compression]

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, the codec used, was not loss-less so trying to compress the files even further won't do much.

Comment: What you want to know is [Information Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) which stipulates a maximum limit for compression of it.  Your MP4s are already compressed, by the codecs they use, and because of the mathematical limits they cannot be compressed any further.